# Why is my onClicklistener unreachable?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have the following code in my Adapter in a recyclerview:

```
public class MyMovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyMovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    Cursor dataCursor;

    public MyMovieAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor,) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataCursor = cursor;

    }

    @Override
    public MyMovieAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_movies_listrow, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        dataCursor.moveToPosition(i);
        viewHolder.my_movie_delete_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("AAAA", "It doesn't print that log on a button click");
            }
        });

        viewHolder.tv_original_title.setText(dataCursor.getString(1));
        Picasso.with(context).load(dataCursor.getString(9)).resize(150,225).into(viewHolder.img_my_movie);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataCursor.getCount();
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView tv_original_title;
        ImageView img_my_movie;
        Button my_movie_delete_button;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);


            tv_original_title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_original_title);
            img_my_movie = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_my_movie);
            my_movie_delete_button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.my_movies_delete_button);
            my_movie_delete_button.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("AAAA", "Neither like that");

        }
    }
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        if (dataCursor == cursor) {
            return null;
        }
        Cursor oldCursor = dataCursor;
        this.dataCursor = cursor;
        if (cursor != null) {
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return oldCursor;
    }
 }
```

And my layout for a row of my list looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="225dp"
            android:id="@+id/img_my_movie"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_original_title"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_my_movie" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/my_movies_delete_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="delete"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_original_title"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_original_title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have try to print a log on a button click two different way as you can see above, without luck. What could be the problem?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Sometimes Log would not get printed Exit with studio and start Again and check it will work but do not restart it Just Exit and Fresh start

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE It doesn't print the log on the buttonclick.

Comment: can you please explain brief what kind of issue you are facing

Comment: @MohitTrivedi I have tried that without luck, i tried to debug as well, but it looks like that this onClick method never visited.

Comment: There is a button on the left, on the Android Monitor tab, that allows you to restart it. Try that first. By the way, have you tried other actions onClick event? Do they work?

Comment: @rofl I tried to Toast as well, didn't appear.

Comment: @GaneshGudghe I would like to log on a buttonclick. It looks like that onClick method never visited.

Comment: @GaborHartyandi; Your code looks fine though. It would be strange that everything is working but your log is simply not logged in logcat. Are you sure you don't see any warnings/stacktraces beforehand in logcat?

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE I tried to debug the code. I put brake point to the log, but  never enters the onClick() method. I tried to restart the app. I run my app on a real device. The view appears how  it should be, but nothing happens on click.

Comment: Why you are setting onClick listener in two place ??

Comment: @Ram I dont set it. I just tried both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many said in the comments above, the problem was with restarting the app. First I went to Monitors in the logcat and closed the running app, and run the app again. The log still didn't appear after restarting the app. Then I uninstalled the app from my device, and run again. The app worked after.

Thanks for the help and your time to help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set this to parent of your row layout android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
and
Replace your code with following code,

```
public class MyMovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyMovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    Cursor dataCursor;

    public MyMovieAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor,) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataCursor = cursor;

    }

    @Override
    public MyMovieAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_movies_listrow, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        dataCursor.moveToPosition(i);
        viewHolder.my_movie_delete_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("AAAA", "It doesn't print that log on a button click");
            }
        });

        viewHolder.tv_original_title.setText(dataCursor.getString(1));
        Picasso.with(context).load(dataCursor.getString(9)).resize(150,225).into(viewHolder.img_my_movie);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataCursor.getCount();
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView tv_original_title;
        ImageView img_my_movie;
        Button my_movie_delete_button;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);


            tv_original_title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_original_title);
            img_my_movie = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_my_movie);
            my_movie_delete_button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.my_movies_delete_button);


        }

            }
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        if (dataCursor == cursor) {
            return null;
        }
        Cursor oldCursor = dataCursor;
        this.dataCursor = cursor;
        if (cursor != null) {
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return oldCursor;
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Gabor Hartyandi Try rajesh's code i hope it will work for you

Comment: try to describe what was the issue instead of posting the solution only. It will help the person to avoid such issues in future.

Comment: set this to parent of your row layout android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: @Rajesh yes, the view appears, how it should be.

Comment: set this to parent of your row layout android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: @RajeshSuthar Thanks for the help, It works now. I just uninstalled the app from the device, and run again. Sorry for the inconvenience.